# Símbolos da operação ternária aparecem na tela

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como pode ser visto na linha abaixo, estou usando uma condição ternária na minha tela:

```
<h:outputText value="#{naturemb.nature.id == null} ? #{msg['cadastrando.nature']} : #{msg['atualizando.nature']}"/>
```

Porém na tela, além do texto mostram os sinais '?' e ':' como pode ser visto na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que o código está no local errado.
Tente desta forma: 
`#{naturemb.nature.id == null ? msg['cadastrando.nature'] : msg['atualizando.nature']}`

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Comment: Aproveitando sua boa vontade, como concateno 2 EL após o ':'?  Ex: msg['atualizando'] msg['nature']